# Conjecture: There are infinitely many $N \in \Bbb{N}$ such that $p$ a prime $p \leq \sqrt{N+1} \implies p \mid N$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, radicals, conjectures, natural-numbers

**Conjecture**.  There are infinitely many $N$ such that if $p$ is a prime $\leq \sqrt{N+1}$ then $p \mid N$.

Is this another hard to prove number theory conjecture, or do you have some idea of how to solve it?

Comment: How many such $N$ have you found?

Comment: @lulu: 4, 6, 12, 18, ..., 30, not 42, ...

Comment: Is it "... if $\forall p\leq \sqrt{N+1}$ ..." or "... if $\exists p\leq \sqrt{N+1}$ ... "?

Comment: @it's for all prime $p$ such that $p^2 - 1 \leq N$ or equiv. $p \leq \sqrt{N+1}$, then...

Comment: Yes, it's easy for very small $N$.  What about larger ones?    How many such $N$ are there less than $10^4$, say?  What's the largest $N$ in that range?

Comment: @lulu it's infinitly many intuitively, just wondering if there's an elementary proof

Comment: I don't find that intuitive at all.  That's why I am asking what the numerical evidence is.

Comment: @lulu I've written code in previous posts of mine.  Didn't really help answer the question though.

Comment: Is there a reason it's difficult to just answer my numerical question?

Comment: Isn't it true for any $N=n!$? Thus the statement is true ...

Comment: @lulu I spend an hour writing code, then this post gets ignored.  Or this post gets ignored.  The latter is easier for me.

Comment: @rtybase can you prove that?  Please make an answer.

Comment: @rtybase there's a subtlety though:  $\sqrt{7! + 1} = 71$ a prime which does not divide $7!$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I'm interpreting your conjecture correctly, it is false. Let's say a number $N$ is an enjoyable number if, for all primes $p\le \sqrt{N+1}$, $p$ divides $N$. So for example, $30$ is an enjoyable number because $\sqrt{31} \approx 5.6$, and all primes $\le 5.6$ divide $30$.

Why can there not be infinitely many enjoyable numbers? Suppose $N$ is an enjoyable number. Then $N$ is divisible by every prime smaller than or equal to $\sqrt{N+1}$. In particular, $N$ is divisible by the product of all such primes. The [prime counting function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime-counting_function) has the lower bound $$
\pi(x)> \frac{x}{\log x}
$$
The product of all primes less than or equal to $\sqrt{N+1}$ is bounded below by $$2^{\pi(\sqrt{N+1})}>2^{\frac{\sqrt{N+1}}{\log(\sqrt{N+1})}} = 4^{\frac{\sqrt{N+1}}{\log(N+1)}}$$
which is clearly asymptotically bigger than $N$, and [computationally is bigger than $N$ for all $N\ge 1473$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=4%5E%28sqrt%28x%2B1%29%2Flog%28x%2B1%29%29%20%3E%20x). Hence all enjoyable numbers must be smaller than $1473$.

---

Update: I did a computer of all integers up to $1473$. The complete set of enjoyable numbers is $\{1,2,4,6,12,18,30\}$. My Haskell code below:

```
-- Integer square root 
isqrt :: (Integral a, Enum a, Ord a) => a -> a 
isqrt n = pred $ head $ filter (\k -> k^2 > n) [1..]

-- checks if the first argument is divisible by the second 
divis :: Integral a => a -> a -> Bool
divis n = (0 == ) . (rem n)

-- checks if the first argument is not divisible by the second 
sivid :: Integral a => a -> a -> Bool
sivid n = (0 /= ) . (rem n)

-- list of all primes 
primes :: (Integral a, Enum a) => [a]
primes = 2:(filter (\ k -> and $ map (sivid k) $ takeWhile (not . ( > k) . (^2)) primes) [3..])

-- multiplies all the primes up to n 
pp :: (Integral a, Enum a, Ord a) => a -> a
pp n = product $ takeWhile ( not . (> n) ) primes

-- checks if a number is enjoyable 
is_enjoyable :: (Integral a, Enum a, Ord a) => a -> Bool
is_enjoyable n = divis n $ pp $ isqrt $ succ n

-- set of all enjoyable numbers 
enjoyables :: [Integer]
enjoyables = filter is_enjoyable [1..1473]
```

Answer (score 3):

If $N$ is divisible by every prime $p\le\sqrt{N+1}$, then $N$ is divisible by the product of all those primes. But the product of all the primes up to $x$ is known to be asymptotic to $e^x$, and $e^{\sqrt{N+1}}$ grows much much faster than $N$. So there are only finitely many such $N$.